Using global or any other method?
I'm currently having an issue getting certain portions of my app to work. I want to add radiobuttons, and a convert button so that users are able to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius and vice versa. When adding the specific functions and variables into the second  window it seems to gray out the options and prevents the code from executing properly.
I've tried adding certain definitions and functions gradually which has worked but am still having difficulty getting it to the proper format that I would like. I've been using the global variable to ensure that I'm only communicating with the second window, but still doesn't seem to process certain functions.
def openNewWindow():
    global NewWindow

    #Creates a new window using Toplevel
    NewWindow = Toplevel(master_window)

    #Sets the title of Toplevel widget
    NewWindow.title("Dave's weather app")

    #Sets the geometry of Toplevel
    NewWindow.geometry('350x350')

#Label widget to show in Toplevel
    Label(NewWindow, text = "Temperature Conversion", fg = 'gold', bg = 'dark blue', font = ('bold, 12')).pack()

#Configures window color
    NewWindow.configure(bg = 'dark blue')

#Temperature input block that allows the user to input a number within the program
    label = Label(NewWindow, text = "Enter Temperature:").pack()

    entry = Entry(NewWindow).pack()

    #Convert button acts as an enter key and allows the program to process the number
    convert_btn = Button(NewWindow, text = "Convert", command = convert_temperature).pack()

    #Result label outputs
    result_label = Label(NewWindow, text = "").pack()

#Defines the formula to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit
def Celsius_to_Fahrenheit(Celsius):
    return (1.8) * Celsius + 32
#Defines the formula to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius
def Fahrenheit_to_Celsius(Fahrenheit):
    return (0.55) * (Fahrenheit - 32)


  







#Main NewWindow welcome screen
master_window = Tk()
master_window.title("Welcome Screen")
master_window.configure(bg = 'dark blue')
master_window.geometry('200x200')


#Welcome label for the master window
label = Label(master_window, text = "Welcome!")
label.pack( pady = 10)

#Button to open Dave's weather app 
btn1 = Button(master_window, text = "Click to open Dave's Weather app", command = openNewWindow)
btn1.pack(expand = True)

#Welcome screen exit button
btn2 = Button(master_window, text = "Exit", command = exit)
btn2.pack(expand = True)


mainloop()


There's no convert_temperature function defined here, so you're hitting a NameError exception in openNewWindow which is causing the elements downstream of that not to show up on the GUI. Specifically, this line hits the exception: convert_btn = Button(NewWindow, text = "Convert", command = convert_temperature).pack()

You may also want to familiarize yourself with PEP8 - following the Python style guide will help you write better Python that's easier for you to debug and for others to read. You should also generally avoid star imports, and declaring and packing widgets on one line, like convert_btn = Button(...).pack() because pack returns None, which means convert_btn is None

And FWIW, you don't need global NewWindow - it's not doing anything here

@Reesecup, Pl see my answer. My code works as you expected

This is the complete code. Radiobuttons should be declared as shown in the code. To get the value of the radiobutton, A string variable with the name tempvar is declared. tempvar = StringVar(). By using tempvar.get(), we can get the value. The string variable should be mapped with the radiobuttons using variable = tempvar. Likewise, the value of the entry is got by entry.get(). Instead of declaring global variables, I've given the function convert_temperature() inside the toplevel window.  The Output is displayed using label.configure. Please note: If widgets are declared as variables with a variable name, It can't be directly packed. It can be packed only in the next line using widget_name.pack()
from tkinter import *


def openNewWindow():
      
    def convert_temperature():
        
        temp = entry.get()
        temp = int(float(temp))
        type = tempvar.get()
        if type == 'celc':
            result = (1.8) * temp + 32
        else: result = (0.55) * (temp - 32)
        result_label.configure(text = result)
    
    

    #Creates a new window using Toplevel
    NewWindow = Toplevel(master_window)

    #Sets the title of Toplevel widget
    NewWindow.title("Dave's weather app")

    #Sets the geometry of Toplevel
    NewWindow.geometry('350x350')

#Label widget to show in Toplevel
    Label(NewWindow, text = "Temperature Conversion", fg = 'gold', bg = 'dark blue', font = ('bold, 12')).pack()

#Configures window color
    NewWindow.configure(bg = 'dark blue')
    
    tempvar = StringVar()
    celc = Radiobutton(NewWindow, variable = tempvar, value = 'celc', text = 'Convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit')  
    celc.pack()
    
    fheit = Radiobutton(NewWindow, variable = tempvar, value = 'fheit', text = 'Convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius')
    fheit.pack()
    
#Please Note when widget is assigned to a variable name, declare variable separately and pack the variable in next line
    label = Label(NewWindow, text = "Enter Temperature:")
    label.pack()

    entry = Entry(NewWindow)
    entry.pack()

    #Convert button acts as an enter key and allows the program to process the number
    convert_btn = Button(NewWindow, text = "Convert", command = convert_temperature)
    convert_btn.pack()

    #Result label outputs
    result_label = Label(NewWindow, text = "")
    result_label.pack()
    
#Main NewWindow welcome screen
master_window = Tk()
master_window.title("Welcome Screen")
master_window.configure(bg = 'dark blue')
master_window.geometry('200x200')


#Welcome label for the master window
label = Label(master_window, text = "Welcome!")
label.pack( pady = 10)

#Button to open Dave's weather app 
btn1 = Button(master_window, text = "Click to open Dave's Weather app", command = openNewWindow)
btn1.pack(expand = True)

#Welcome screen exit button
btn2 = Button(master_window, text = "Exit", command = exit)
btn2.pack(expand = True)


master_window.mainloop()

